# Cordova 4 any access file.fullPath will result in error code 5

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-3

I'm using Cordova(4), ngCordova(latest) and ionic (b13) to capture image and audio
I can get the fullPath from the callback fine.
But when I try to access it with any function of $cordovaFile, I end up with error code 5 (which is encoding error?!) on both iOS8 & Android 4.4.2

Trying to use window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI without luck.

Can anyone share some working code that can read from fullPath 
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/xxxxx/tmp/photo_001.jpg
&
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/xxxxx/tmp/audio_001.wav